# How to send authentication from one site to another

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, node.js, mongodb

Currently I have a server running mongodb which has a users collection implemented and a NodeJS API that communicates with the database and using passportJS for authentication.

Now there is another application that is written in asp.net core, and uses another database (SQL) for its users.

These two are supposed to work like they are one application, i.e. they run under the same domain and are linked to each other, we want it so that when you open the asp.net application from the NodeJS site you seamlessly get logged in (with same username). Problem is that they run on different user database...

Is there a way to achieve this? May sound silly but this is a task I received. If I was not clear enough let me know.

Comment: So you would need to be logged into two separate accounts to access both databases?

Comment: @SethMcClaine as it is, then you have to have an account on both applications. Ideally we want to have the same accounts, but the .net application has other tables  that depend on the userID of the SQL for other usage.